# Chai should be bignumber equal doesn't work

Tags: testing, solidity, chai

I am requireing chai like this

```js
const BigNumber = web3.BigNumber;
require('chai').use(require('chai-bignumber')(BigNumber)).should();
```

and during test

```js
let balance = await contract.balanceOf(accountToReceive);
should.be.bignumber.eql(countToSend); //works fine
ownerBalance = await contract.balanceOf(owner);
should.be.bignumber.equal(settings.initialSupply.mul(utils.toBN(10).pow(_decimals)).sub(countToSend)); // gives en error
```

Error code is

> ```
> AssertionError: expected <BN: 94e47b8d68171533ffff9c> to equal <BN: 94e47b8d68171533ffff9c>
>      + expected - actual
>
>      at Context.<anonymous> (test/MOS.test.js:79:33)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> ```

Comment: It occurs that problem is in .sub but still I'm not able to fix it.

Comment: Why are you using `equal`?  They will be different BigNumber objects won't they?  I think you should be using `eql`.  Remember that `expect({ a: 1 }).to.equal({ a: 1 });` fails because they're not the same object.  But `expect({ b: 2 }).to.eql({ b: 2 });` passes because it does a deep comparison.

Comment: I am getting same error just in place of equal there is deep equal
`AssertionError: expected <BN: 94e47b8d68171533ffff9c> to deep equal <BN: 94e47b8d68171533ffff9c>`

Comment: UPDATE: problem is in .add and .sub. When I convert BN to number add them and then convert them back to BN it will work. But some numbers are just too big to bi converted to Number type

Comment: UPDATE: I've solved the problem with using BigInt, doing all math with BigInt objects and then utils.toBn(someBigIntNumber.toString()) but I think there should be a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've mentioned in update, you can use JS Bigint, do all your math with it and then just pass it to BN constructor as a string, like
`utils.toBN((1000000n * 5748553687688487n).toString())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the chai plugin for BN.js which should work with should.

See its usage at:
https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-bn/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue with my code. I found a good solution which works for me.

Try the following:

```js
require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised')).should();
.use(bnChai(web3.utils.BN));
```

Comment: Thanks for reaction, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, the answer is simple
just use the `expect` function of chai with `to.be.bignumber.equal`

**Example:**

```js
const { expect } = chai;
const { BN } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

const exp_val = new BN(); // any value
expect(contract.method()).to.be.bignumber.equal(exp_value);
```